# Optimize code with too many iterations and conditions

Tags: python, optimization, refactoring

I'm trying to optimize this piece of code in my app because I feel like I have too many conditions and nested cycles (and so does my machine).

Here's a snippet:

```
def some_kind_of_method(data):

    # data is a dict() object

    for key, value in data.viewitems():
        if type(value) is OrderedDict:

            if key == 'something':
                do_method_1(key, value)

                for sub_key, sub_value in value.viewitems():

                    stored_value = do_method_2(sub_key, sub_value)

                    if type(sub_value) is OrderedDict:
                        for sub_key2, sub_value2 in sub_value.viewitems():
                            do_method_3(sub_key2, sub_value2, extra_var=store_value)

                    else:
                        do_method_3(sub_key, sub_value)
            else:
                for sub_key, sub_value in value.viewitems():
                    do_action(sub_key, sub_value)

        elif type(value) is list:
            for lst_item in value:

                do_method_1(key, value)

                for sub_lst_key, sub_lst_value in lst_item.viewitems():
                    do_method_2(sub_lst_key, sub_lst_value)

                    if type(sub_lst_value) is OrderedDict:
                        for sub_key2, sub_value2 in sub_lst_value.viewitems():
                            do_method_3(sub_key2, sub_value2, extra_var=stored_value)

                    else:
                        do_method_3(sub_lst_key, sub_lst_value)

        else:
            do_method_3(key, value)

   return True
```

Any suggestions to this still-novice developer?

Comment: You need to post it in Code Review with an explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thank you for your reply.